# DATEADD and missing dates

Tags: excel, dateadd, powerpivot, dax

How do you reliably add 10 months to a date in the DAX formula for a PowerPivot calculated column?

My first attempt only works for dates that already exist in the EventDate column.

```
=DATEADD(Dates[EventDate], 10, month)
```

As Chris Webb wrote in his blog [DATEADD is unreliable](http://cwebbbi.wordpress.com/2012/01/06/the-dax-dateadd-function-and-missing-dates/) as it returns blanks whenever the resulting date is not found in the EventDate column.

My second attempt always returns data, but the day of the month is incorrect.

```
=[EventDate] + 10 * 31
```

Notes: All dates in EventDate are on the first day of the month. I am using PowerPivot for Excel 2010. The formula is for the financial year hierarchy in a date dimension.

Is there a better way to add months in DAX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an old one but may still be of use......

```
=IF(
    DAY([Eventdate])>DAY(EOMONTH([Eventdate],10)),
             DATE(year(eomonth([Eventdate],10)),month(eomonth([Eventdate],10)),day(EOMONTH([Eventdate],10))),
             DATE(year(eomonth([Eventdate],10)),month(eomonth([Eventdate],10)),day([Eventdate]))
    )
```

This assumes that where the 'partner' 10 months on has fewer days it will default to the last day of that month.

HTH
Jacob

Answer (score 2):

Another way to add time to a date using DAX is using [EDATE()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634544.aspx), this function add months and it will return the right day of the month. For example:

```
Foo = EDATE(Dates[EventDate], 10)
```